# Kernel crash with RandomChoice

Tags: bugs, random, crash

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 and persisting through 13.0.1 or later (case: 4948255). It has been fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I use Mathematica 12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64 bit). While playing with some code inspired by [this recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269800/27951), I stumbled upon a call to `RandomChoice` that seems to reliably crash my kernel. Playing with different methods for the random number generator, I noticed that the `"Congruential"` method does not handle weighted choices well.

First, this code executes repeatedly and with no problem:

```
SeedRandom[20220622, Method -> "Congruential"];
RandomChoice[Range[10, 13]]
(* Out: 12 *)
```

The following similar call, which should in principle be equivalent but uses explicit constant weights, reliably **crashed my kernel** every time I ran it:

```
(* BEWARE - POTENTIAL KERNEL CRASH *)

SeedRandom[20220622, Method -> "Congruential"];
RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1} -> Range[10, 13]]
```

Other values for the weights (e.g. `{1, 2, 2, 1}` or `{1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}`, or corresponding lists of machine-precision numbers) all have the same behavior, i.e. they lead to a crash.

[Other generators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95533/27951) are not affected:

```
ClearAll[tester]
tester[method_String] := (
  SeedRandom[20220622, Method -> method]; 
  {method, RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1} -> Range[10, 13]]}
)

TableForm[
 tester /@ {
   "ParallelGenerator", "ParallelMersenneTwister",
   "MersenneTwister", "MKL",
   "Rule30CA", "Rule50025CA",
   "ExtendedCA", "Legacy", "OpenSSL"}
]
```

[image: list of results from the other random number generators]

### Questions:

- Is this a bug, or am I mishandling the random number framework?
- Is there a first-principle reason why the `"Congruential"` method cannot handle weights?
- Is this behavior version-dependent? OS-dependent?

Comment: I observe the same thing with MMA version 13.0.1

Comment: "Is there a first-principle reason why the `"Congruential"` method cannot handle weights?" - there isn't, which is all the more reason to [report this crash to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Comment: The kernel crashes even in version 8.0.4, this seems to be an old bug.

Comment: Reporting this as a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you! If your report generates a tracking token that you can share, would you mind adding it to the question?

Comment: I think you have to contact Tech Support for tracking. As far as I am aware reports filed internally do not have external tracking. We do have a field for "External reporter" but I can only fill it in when a full name is available. (The advantage is that external reporters get notified when fixes are made.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Got it. I've reported it as well. I'll update the question with a case number when I get one.

Comment: A [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPiV1.png). I am on a mac with `13.2.0`. It'd be nice if we could test on Linux or Windows

Comment: It works fine on `13.2.0` on Windows 11.