# How to simulate hysteresis loop for a ferrimagnetic material

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, physics, simulation

I am trying to modify a ferromagnetic hysteresis loop to ferrimagnetic hysteresis loop.
Below is the equation I used for ferromagnetic simulation :

[image]

Below is the code for above equation:

```
c[h_, b_, s_] := 1/h ArcTanh[b/s]; 
B0[h_, b_, s_, x_] := 
 s  UnitStep[x] ( (
   Tanh[1.3 c[h, b, s] (x - h)] + Tanh[1.3 h c[h, b, s]])/(
   1 + Tanh[1.3 h c[h, b, s]])); 
B1[h_, b_, s_, x_] := s  Tanh[c[h, b, s] (x + h)]; 
B2[h_, b_, s_, x_] := s  Tanh[c[h, b, s] (x - h)]
H[h_, b_, s_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 Which[-200 <= \[Alpha] <= 0, \[Alpha] + 200, 0 <= \[Alpha] < 400, 
  200 - \[Alpha], 400 <= \[Alpha] < 800, \[Alpha] - 600]
B[h_, b_, s_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 Which[-200 <= \[Alpha] <= 0, B0[h, b, s, \[Alpha] + 200], 
  0 <= \[Alpha] <= 400, B1[h, b, s, 200 - \[Alpha]], 
  400 <= \[Alpha] <= 800, B2[h, b, s, \[Alpha] - 600]]
g[h_, b_, s_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 Plot[{B0[h, b, s, x], B1[h, b, s, x], B2[h, b, s, x]}, {x, -200, 
   200}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-2, 2}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Row[{H, "  (A/m)"}], Row[{B , "  (T)"}]}, 
  ImageSize -> {550, 250}, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}], {H[h, b, 
      s, \[Alpha]], B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]]}]]

\[Theta]1[h_, b_, s_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 If[B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] >= 0, (B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] - 2) \[Pi]/
   2 , -B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] \[Pi]/2];  \[Theta]2[h_, b_, 
  s_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 If[B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] >= 0, (2 - B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]]) \[Pi]/2 , 
  2 \[Pi] + B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] \[Pi]/2]

Manipulate[
 Column[{g[h, b, s, \[Alpha]], magnet[h, b, s, \[Alpha]]}], {{s, 1.8, 
   Style[Row[{"saturation field ", Subscript[B, S], "  (T)"}]]}, 1.6, 
  2.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{h, 35, 
   Style[Row[{"coercivity ", Subscript[H, C], "  (A/m)"}]]}, 20, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1.2, Style[Row[{"remanence ", Subscript[B, R], "  (T)"}]]}, 1, 
  1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Alpha], -200, "cycle magnetic field"}, -200, 795, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {h, b, s, \[Alpha]}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I am trying to add additional term to this equation .Below is the modified equation:

[image]

I am trying to add the chi term to the manipulate function but not winning.
I really appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can do is to modify your definition of the function g[ ]:

```
g[h_, b_, s_, \[Alpha]_, chi_] := 
Plot[{B0[h, b, s, x] + chi, B1[h, b, s, x] + chi, 
   B2[h, b, s, x] + chi}, {x, -200, 200}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-3, 3}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Row[{H, "  (A/m)"}], Row[{B, "  (T)"}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {550, 250}, 
   Epilog -> Inset[Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[{0, 0}]}], {H[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] + chi, B[h, b, s, \[Alpha]] + chi}]]
```

and then the Manipulate becomes:

```
Manipulate[g[h, b, s, \[Alpha], chi], 
 {{s, 1.8, Style[Row[{"saturation field ", Subscript[B, S], "  (T)"}]]}, 1.6, 2.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{h, 35,  Style[Row[{"coercivity ", Subscript[H, C], "  (A/m)"}]]}, 20, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{b, 1.2, tyle[Row[{"remanence ", Subscript[B, R], "  (T)"}]]}, 1, 1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{\[Alpha], -200, "cycle magnetic field"}, -200, 795, 1}, {chi, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: This worked .Thank you for your help. Really appreciate your assistance

Comment: Sorry to intrude, do you have an idea for [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272303/18437)?